# An issue with a project

Tags: python

```
print('Enter student name: ')
StudentName = input( )

print('What degree program are you in?: ')
Degree = input( )

print("How many credits are required to graduate?: ")
Credits_Required = input(int( ))

print("How many credits have you acquired?: ")
Credits_Attained = input(int( ))

Credits_Needed = Credits_Required - Credits_Attained

print("The student\'s name is " + StudentName)
print("Degree Program: " + Degree)
print(StudentName, "needs", Credits_Needed, "more credits.")
```

it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    Credits_Needed = Credits_Required-Credits_Attained
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It makes little sense in doing ```input(int())```.   What you probably wanted was ```int(input())```

Answer (score 0):

redits_Needed = Credits_Required-Credits_Attained

The two number should be int or float, not str

```
print('Enter student name: ')
StudentName = input( )

print('What degree program are you in?: ')
Degree = input( )

print("How many credits are required to graduate?: ")
Credits_Required = int(input())

print("How many credits have you acquired?: ")
Credits_Attained = int(input())

Credits_Needed = Credits_Required - Credits_Attained

print("The student\'s name is " + StudentName)
print("Degree Program: " + Degree)
print(StudentName, "needs", Credits_Needed, "more credits.")
```

change input to int is : int(input())